# rsyslog dynamic file filter

Tags: ubuntu, remote, rsyslog

I'm trying to get my local /var/log/syslog file under control. My current structure is to log remote files to /var/log/juniper/syslog/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log.  Below are my configurations.

### rsyslog.conf

```
/etc# cat rsyslog.conf
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging $ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception $ModLoad imudp $UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
# $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages $RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
# $FileOwner syslog $FileGroup adm $FileCreateMode 0640 $DirCreateMode 0755 $Umask 0022 $PrivDropToUser syslog $PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Where to place spool files
# $WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
# $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

################
#### RULES #####
################

# This one is the template to generate the log filename dynamically, depending on the client's IP address. 
$template JUNIPER,"/var/log/juniper/syslog/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log"

# Log all messages to the dynamically formed file. Now each clients log will be under a separate directory which is formed by the template FILENAME.
*.* ?JUNIPER

/etc#
```

### 50-default.conf

```
/etc/rsyslog.d# cat 50-default.conf
#  Default rules for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see rsyslog.conf(5) and /etc/rsyslog.conf

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*                       -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*                          -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*                         -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
#mail.info                      -/var/log/mail.info
#mail.warn                      -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       cron,daemon.none;\
#       mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg                                :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#       *.=debug;*.=info;\
#       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
#
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=debug;*.=info;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
/etc/rsyslog.d#
```

`*.* ?JUNIPER` is effectively logging everything from everyone (including locahost) to the template `$template JUNIPER,"/var/log/juniper/syslog/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log”`.

`*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog` is then doubling my log files to the regular /var/log/syslog file.

How can I filter these results down so that the localhost is logging to it’s original location (/var/log/syslog) and remote clients only log to their respective location (/var/log/juniper/syslog/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remediate this issue, I commented out `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` and added in 2 IP-based filter conditions.

```
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' then /var/log/syslog 
if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then ?JUNIPER
```

Essentially, this sends everything coming from localhost to /var/log/syslog. Remote host logs are then sent to their respective dynamic directories.